# Parse.com android saveAllInBackground

Tags: parse-platform

i've a problem using ParseObject.saveAllInBackground on my android app

```
   List<ParseObject> objList = new ArrayList<ParseObject>();
     for(ParseObject object : myobjectsbeendet)
     {
         ParseObject obj = ParseObject.createWithoutData("games", object.getObjectId());
         object.put("playershow", "0");
         //object.saveInBackground();
         objList.add(obj);
     }
    progress.show();
     ParseObject.saveAllInBackground(objList, new SaveCallback() {
         @Override
         public void done(ParseException e) {
             if (e == null) {

                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             } else {
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
             progress.dismiss();

         }
     });
```

i've already queried all objects and saved them to a static variable (myobjectsbeendet). now i want to change the value "playershow" to "0" --> nothing happens if i use saveAllInBackground. if i uncomment the line 
//object.saveInBackground(); and save the data for each object in the for loop all works fine... not using saveAllInBackground

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer......

I was using:
`object.put("playershow", "0");`

instead of:
`obj.put("playershow", "0");`